# RDLC Report Viewer Not Show in Form

Tags: c#

I use VB 2017 Community Edition and SQL Server 2012 Express edition.

I have a `.rdlc` report install from Tools Extension and Update Tab in MicroSoft RDLC Report Designer then report viewer drug in form it will show below form not in form. however right click on project and manage NewGet package and install Microsoft reporting services report viewer control winform and install it the report viewer show in form. so every create every project then install above package. how to install at once for all project